# Copying and Pasting Worksheet Name to another Worksheet that is not active, without using select/activate

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to speed up my code by re-writing it not using select.

I have three tabs, and I want to paste the tab name next to the data that appears in that respective tab, without selecting the tab.

However, I am finding that when I run the code, say for example on sheet 1, it works for sheet 1 but when it trys to do the same for sheet 2 it fails with error "Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error."

Please see below my code.

```
Sub Create_Reports_NEWWWW()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim LastRow As Integer
Dim LastColumn As Integer

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook

'copy sheet name to right of raw data on each sheet
LastRow = wb.Sheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
LastColumn = wb.Sheets(1).Cells(4, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
wb.Sheets(1).Range(Cells(4, LastColumn + 1), Cells(LastRow, LastColumn + 1)) = wb.Sheets(1).Name

LastRow = wb.Sheets(2).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
LastColumn = wb.Sheets(2).Cells(4, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
wb.Sheets(2).Range(Cells(4, LastColumn + 1), Cells(LastRow, LastColumn + 1)) = wb.Sheets(2).Name

LastRow = wb.Sheets(3).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
LastColumn = wb.Sheets(3).Cells(4, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
wb.Sheets(3).Range(Cells(4, LastColumn + 1), Cells(LastRow, LastColumn + 1)) = wb.Sheets(3).Name
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here it is:

```
Sub Create_Reports_NEWWWW()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim lastRow As Integer
Dim lastColumn As Integer

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook

With wb.Sheets(1)
'copy sheet name to right of raw data on each sheet
lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
lastColumn = .Cells(4, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
.Range(.Cells(4, lastColumn + 1), .Cells(lastRow, lastColumn + 1)) = .Name
End With

With wb.Sheets(2)
lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
lastColumn = .Cells(4, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
.Range(.Cells(4, lastColumn + 1), .Cells(lastRow, lastColumn + 1)) = .Name
End With

With wb.Sheets(3)
lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
lastColumn = .Cells(4, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
.Range(.Cells(4, lastColumn + 1), .Cells(lastRow, lastColumn + 1)) = .Name
End With

End Sub
```

You can't use `Cells` on non-active Worksheets. You need to use `wb.Sheets(2).Cells(x,y)`

The `With`-blocks in this code are just there for saving space. Every `.Range` or `.Cells` refers to the  e.g. `wb.Sheets(1)` and could be seen as `wb.Sheets(1).Cells(x,y)..`

And btw: it's very good to stop using `Select` and `Activate`, you should also avoid `ActiveWorkbook` or `ActiveWorksheet`. It's very unreliable and you'll never know what users will do. ;)

HTH

Comment: ++ You are correct. i would also recommend adding the DOTS before rows and columns.

Comment: Because I know. :P Do you want me to explain it? ;)

Comment: What does adding the DOTS do?

Comment: @TomBeasley: That my dear friend is a good question :) I have explained it [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-vba). And [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19985345/vba-excel-compability-mode#comment29753337_19985345) is a direct link demonstrating what could go wrong.

Comment: I see. But when you say it will fail because of the excel 2003 vs 2007 scenario having different numbers of rows, in what scenario would it fail

Comment: See the comment below that question and then see the example in the question in the second link @TomBeasley